# Application prints "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005" and does not halt

Tags: java, debugging, remote-debugging

I start code execution with the typical arguments:

```
java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005 myPackage.myMainClassname
```

Application starts, prints "Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005" and... goes further! Without any attempt to wait for connection. I CAN connect to it during execution and debugging itself works. But why does the application not wait for connection from debugger?

Looks like something is broken in my configuration, but I cannot figure out the root cause. I tried several ways to specify debug settings, different ports, run as administrator, turn off firewalls - nothing helps.

Comment: What's this argument: `suspend=n`?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to specify `suspend=y` if you want it to wait for connection. Your debugging is working. If you try to connect you will be able to. Most probably you are just used to using `suspend=y` which blocks until the connection is established.

The behavior is expected when `suspend=n`.

Answer (score 5):

> Select menu "Run/Edit Configurations".  Check: "Edit configurations"
>   dialog pops up. Click on "+" icon, select "Remote" from the list.
>   Check: new configuration with name "Unnamed" appears under "Remote"
>   category. Change configuration name to something more sensible, like
>   "Remote Debug". Don't change any other parameters, just click "OK".
>
> Run web-application under the debugger
>
> Start gradle task "appStartDebug" under IntelliJ IDEA. Attention: do
>   not try to start this task under the debugger. Run it in normal mode.
>   Check: you should see "Listening for transport dt_socket at address:
>   5005" in "Run" output window. Select menu "Run/Run...", select "Remote
>   Debug" configuration, select "Debug" command. Check: you should see
>   "Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:5005', transport:
>   'socket'" in "Debug" output window.

Now your web-application is running under the debugger: you
 can set breakpoints, watch/inspect variables etc.etc.

Comment: Why do you assume he is using IntelliJ idea?